# Geofencing API with initial trigger set won't fire callback even when inside the fence while activating

Tags: android, google-api, android-geofence

I have a service, that activates multiple geofences for various locations. I have set the initial triggers for both exit and enter, but for some reason I won't get those initial callbacks.. However, this is only happening on some devices. I have another phone next to me, that is getting those callbacks with the same version of app installed

So the real question is, are there any environment conditions that could affect reporting initial fence status back to the app?

Comment: Hey @koperko, did you find a solution for this? I have both dwell and exit as initial triggers, and when I'm inside my geofence the exit event fires but the dwell never happens. Same deal if I change dwell to enter.